# MS Graph SDK retrive mailboxSettings return invalid user error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I tried to use MS Graph API to implement a backend API to access other users email setting (for getting out-of-office message). As it is backend API, client credential flow is used. I already granted the permissions **"MailboxSettings.Read"** and **"MailboxSettings.ReadWrite"** with application type.

1. I used my free Azure account for testing. Assume my login account is **test@hotmail.com**, then my Azure domain is testhotmail.onmicrosoft.com.
   I created one more user **client@testhotmail.onmicrosoft.com**
2. I can get the result using Graph Explorer as below

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test@hotmail.com
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test@hotmail.com/mailboxSettings

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/client@testhotmail.onmicrosoft.com
```

But it return error for below using Graph Explorer

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "ErrorInvalidUser",
> "message": "The requested user 'client@testhotmail.onmicrosoft.com' is invalid."
> } }

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/client@testhotmail.onmicrosoft.com/mailboxSettings
```

3a. If call by MS Graph SDK to get the user info for **client@testhotmail.onmicrosoft.com** as below, it is success

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
   AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
    
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
    
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    
var user = await graphClient.Users["client@testhotmail.onmicrosoft.com"].Request().GetAsync();
```

3b. If call by MS Graph SDK to get the user info for **test@hotmail.com**, it returns error

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
> Message: Resource 'test@hotmail.com' does not exist or one of its
> queried reference-property objects are not present.

```
var user = await graphClient.Users["test@hotmail.com"].Request().GetAsync();
```

4. If call by MS Graph SDK to get the mailbox setting as below, it returned error

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: ErrorInvalidUser Message: The
> requested user 'test@hotmail.com' is invalid.

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
   AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
    
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
    
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var mail = await graphClient.Users["test@hotmail.com"].Request().Select("MailboxSettings").GetAsync();
```

Or returned error for below

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: ResourceNotFound Message:
> Resource could not be discovered.

```
var mail = await graphClient.Users["client@testhotmail.onmicrosoft.com"].Request().Select("MailboxSettings").GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using hotmail.com , as per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java?tabs=aad) you should also have either a personal Microsoft account with a mailbox on Outlook.com, or a Microsoft work or school account.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But I need to implement it as backend API and so client credential flow instead of authorization code flow should be used

Comment: thanks for the update , i noticed that you used Hotmail , i updated my answer ,please take a look , thanks .

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var user = await graphClient.Users["xx@xx.onmicrosoft.com"]
    .Request()
    .Select("MailboxSettings")
    .GetAsync();
var automaticRepliesSetting = user.MailboxSettings.AutomaticRepliesSetting;
```

Could you pls try this? By the way you may also try to add the 2 application permissions which mentioned [in the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions): `MailboxSettings.Read, MailboxSettings.ReadWrite`. And the most important is, your error message is `invalid user`, so I'm afraid you can use `user_PrincipalName` instead of `myuser@hotmail.com`. You can try to get the `user_id` in Azure AD potal or from the result for `await graphClient.Users["myuser@hotmail.com"].Request().GetAsync();`.

Comment: If I call by user ID, it returned error "Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ResourceNotFound. Message: Resource could not be discovered.". Or if I omit the 
Select("MailboxSettings"), the user.MailboxSettings is null

Comment: `ResourceNotFound` whether the user `myuser@hotmail.com` had calendar? I mean, for me, I used to have an internel user in our tenant, I can use my own account to sign in Azure portal, but my user account doesn't have an M365 license, so I don't have a mail in this account, after I have a license for this account , I have the mail and I can also see calendar for this account.

Comment: I just want to make sure if the user account have correct license?